# JavaScript: Are all Standard Built-In Objects actually constructor functions?

Tags: javascript

I have been diving into JavaScript recently, and after spending several months on it I am still confused about some of the internals.

Specifically, I was trying to wrap my head around the so-called [Standard Built-In Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects).

**What I Know**

1. All functions in JavaScript, both built-in and user-created, are objects (`function objects`)
2. Difference between `general objects` and `function objects` is that `function objects` implement the `[[Call]]` property (and can thus be invoked)
3. All `function objects` implement the `.prototype` property, which represents the prototype of all objects created with the `function object` as a constructor

**Questions**

1. Are all the `Standard Built-In Objects` actually `function objects` (i.e. constructor functions)?
2. Do all (and only) `function objects` implement `.prototype`?
3. Are the right terms `general object` vs `function object`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> All function objects implement the `.prototype` property, which represents the prototype of all objects created with the function object as a constructor

No. Only constructor functions do that. There are functions that are no constructors (i.e. they have a [[call]] but no [[construct]] internal method), they throw an error when you try to use them with `new` (as do some functions that have a [[construct]] internal method, but throw nonetheless).

And technically, not even constructor functions necessarily need a `.prototype`. You could implement a builtin that can be constructed but does not have a `.prototype` property. It's true however that all native constructor functions do have one.

> Are all the Standard Built-In Objects actually function objects?

No. Consider the `Math`, `JSON`, `Atomics` or `Reflect` built-in objects. They're not functions at all.

> function objects (i.e. constructor functions)?

No. Consider the `parseInt`, `JSON.stringify` or `Array.prototype.slice` functions (and many more globals, static and prototype methods). They're not constructors at all.

> Do all (and only) function objects implement `.prototype`?

No. There is nothing special about the `.prototype` property, except that it is usually used on a `function` when constructing an instance with `new`. But every object can have or can not have a `.prototype` property.

> Are the right terms general object vs function object?

No, "general objects" is not an official term. I'd name them *non-callable* objects and [*callable* objects](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#table-6) if I had to (the latter term is used in the spec).

Comment: Thanks Bergi. But only constructor functions have a `.prototype` property natively? General objects (i.e. not function objects), do not have this property by default right? I guess it only really makes sense for constructor functions, as it is used to set the `__proto__` of new objects created with that function.

Comment: Also, is `general objects` the official term for objects that are not `function objects`?

Comment: @Magnus Well `{prototype: 123}` is a native object that has one but it not a function (constructor or otherwise). True, I don't know of any built-in one that looks like this, but there's nothing that would prevent it.

Comment: Oh, one other thing: I inspected the built-in function object `Function` and it has neither `[[Call]]` or `[[Construct]]` methods. Same with `Object`. `console.log(Function)` shows these properties: `[[Scopes]]`, `arguments`, `caller`, `length`, `name`, `prototype`, `__proto__`. Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: @Magnus They are internal. Inspecting an object doesn't show them (like many others that the object has). Notice that `[[scopes]]` and `__proto__` are not actual properties either, they are just displayed to represent some internal values.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi. Last question: Is there any way to see what internal properties an object has?

Comment: @Magnus No. And it's not even guaranteed that these actually exist in the engine implementation. They are just used in the specification document do *describe* how the language should *behave*.

Answer (score 1):

1. No, some built-in functions throw an exception if you try to use them with `new` (`Symbol` comes to mind).
2. The prototype concept only applies to functions, though you can create an object with anything you want as the immediate parent in its prototype chain with `Object.create()`
3. All functions are objects, but not all objects are functions.

To clarify 2, all objects have a prototype chain with zero or more objects arranged in (effectively) a list. The automatic setting of a new object's prototype chain based on constructor function `.prototype` value only applies to functions, but that's sort-of tautological because a function is the only thing that can be a constructor.

Comment: Thanks Pointy. Surprising how MDN (and the web in general) lack a good high-level explanation of built-ins and object wrappers, constructor functions and `.prototype` property vs __proto__ (the prototype chain). Follow-up question regarding point 3: Is it called `general objects` and `function objects`? Are those the official terms? And, regarding point 2: The so-called `global Object` from which all other objects descend (prototype link) is really `Object.prototype`, not `Object`, correct? Finally, regarding 1: `Symbol` is a primitive, but most of the other built-ins are `function objects`?

Comment: Well there's no "official" terminology that I know of for objects versus function objects; generally people use the term "object" when talking/writing about objects in general, and "function" when talking about functions in particular. Functions really are objects, and pretty much anything you can do with a plain object you can also do with a function (add attributes, remove attributes, etc).

Comment: The `Symbol` built-in is indeed a function (and therefore a function object).