# Can new be applied to any function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, oop

Many sources like [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) and [this tutorial](https://javascript.info/constructor-new) define a concept called "constructor" that should be used with the `new` keyword to create an instance in traditional OOP's sense. But what "constructor" means is not formally stated.

It seems to me that literally any function can be used with `new`. (Though function without any manipulation to `this` in its definition is not particularly useful when `new`ed, because it merely returns an empty object). Is this correct?

Comment: yes, we can apply a new on a function, and it is not always empty, it can have variables, it can also be a closure, in JS everything is object, even the functions

Comment: No, there are some functions that will throw when you try to use `new` on them.

Comment: yes, not any functions

Comment: @Bergi could you give some examples of functions that can not be `new`ed?

Comment: Have a look at the answers to [How to check if a Javascript function is a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40922531/1048572), [Are there any JS objects for which IsCallable is false but IsConstructor is true?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50109554/1048572) and maybe [JavaScript: Are all Standard Built-In Objects actually constructor functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49431846/1048572) for the technical details

Comment: @wlnirvana Arrow functions, class methods, many builtins, and of course `function Example() { if (new.target) throw new TypeError("Don't new() me!"); }` :-)

Answer (score -1):

When you use the new keyword, it creates a new object. When you create an instance of a class with new, it creates an object, and any properties in the constructor method will be initialized in the object as well.